# Linear inhomogenous diff eqn using undetermined coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $y''(t) -y'(t) -2y(t) = 3e^{-t} $

Trying to find the particular solution i end up with a $0$ on the left hand side: $$ Ae^{-x} + Ae^{-x} -2Ae^{-x} = 3e^{-x}$$ So that leads me to believe the solution is simply $C_1 e^{-x} +C_2 e^{2x}$ Am I correct or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Make for the particular solution the ansatz $$y_p=e^{-t}(At+B)$$

Comment: SO $y_p = 3e^{-t}$ ?

Comment: No, $$y_p=-\frac{1}{3}e^{-t}(1+3t)$$

Comment: So I get $$-2e^{-t}(At+B) - (-e^{-t}(At + B) + Ae^{-t}) +e^{-t}(At + B) -Ae^{-t} -Ae^{-t} = 3e^{-t} \rightarrow -3Ae^{-t} = 3e^{-t}$$ Are you you able to see where I went wrong? I just put the ansatz into the equation.